# Inline editing in jQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have developed a jqgrid and adding an inline editing functionality. The problem I am facing is when I pass data of row (two columns) to my method in controller it just passes 2nd column data and in first column data it just passes the null value. I don't kow what silly thing I am doing. In my js file, I wrote:

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {

        if (id) {
            alert("You are editing it");
            //jQuery('#Grid').jqGrid('restoreRow', last);
            jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
            last = id;
            var selRowId = $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            $('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'TABLE_NAME');
            $('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'TABLE_ALIAS_NAME');

        }
    },
    editurl: "/MyApp/Edit",
```

and in controller method

```
public void Edit(string TABLE_NAME, string TABLE_ALIAS_NAME)
```

but it passes the null value for `TABLE_NAME` and correct value for `TABLE_ALIAS_NAME`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve formatting. I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So I got my silly mistake by myself. I thought to post my answer. By making the `key:true` for the column of `TABLE_NAME`, I got it to work.